# Webpack devServer Livereload for Wordpress localhost

Tags: wordpress, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I use Webpack to build file and for Wordpress theme.

My website running via Xampp with address is http://localhost/simple

How can I build webpack -watch to refresh Web address using devServer:

My directories:

```
- scss
  + base.scss
- src
  + app.js
- public
  + bundle.js
  + style.css
```

I use devServer like this but it does not automatically refresh:

```
 devServer: {
    publicPath: "/",
    contentBase: "./public",
    hot: true
  },
```

Can you support me for this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You also need webpack to run your development environment.

This 'devServer: hot' only enables webpack's Hot Module Replacement feature. In the webpack documentation it is stated that [webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/) is required to enable hot module replacement.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

devServer: {
  hot: true
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
]
```